# Reshape data in hdf5 file

Tags: reshape, hdf

I have a huge hdf5 file with shape (1000000, 2100).

The information in each row is of the form (x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, ....x700, y700, z700)

I am trying to convert it into the shape (1000000, 3, 700), where the format is 
(1000000, 1, ) for x like x1, x2, ..., x700.

The same for y and z.

I am currently doing this using:

```
for ievt in range(nevts):
    for i in range(int(data.shape[1]/3)):
        h5_dataset[ievt][0][i] = data.at[ievt, 3*i+0]
        h5_dataset[ievt][1][i] = data.at[ievt, 3*i+1]
        h5_dataset[ievt][2][i] = data.at[ievt, 3*i+2]
```

Is there a faster way I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this:

```
np_tmp = data.to_numpy(dtype=np.float16)
np_data = np_tmp.reshape(1000000, 700, 3)

h5f = h5py.File('Process.h5', 'w')
h5f.create_dataset('pf_particles', data=np_data)
```

Much faster than running any loops